# remote object AND condition

Tags: remote-objects

I've tried using an AND condition in my remote object. I keep getting an error. Here is what I have based on a help [article](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000213750&language=en_US&type=1). It works when there is only a single condition. Once I add two it doesn't work.

```
// On my VF page
// <apex:remoteObjects >
//    <apex:remoteObjectModel name="Group" fields="Id,Name" />
// </apex:remoteObjects>


    var queue = new SObjectModel.Group();
    var criteria = {
                    where: {
                      Name: {like: event.target.value +'%'},
                      Type: {eq: 'Queue'}
                    }
                   };
    queue.retrieve( criteria, function(err, records, event) {
      if (err) {
        alert(err.message);
      }
      var records = event.result.records;
      console.log(records);
    })
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I presume you're getting the following error:

> Invalid criteria specified for retrieval. ValidationError [code=11, message=Data does not match any schemas from "oneOf", path=/where, schemaKey=null]

---

You can only specify fields to filter if they are specified as part of the remoteObjectModel. You need to change your code as follows:

```
<apex:remoteObjects >
   <apex:remoteObjectModel name="Group" fields="Id,Name,Type" />
</apex:remoteObjects>
```

As a side note, it's not necessary to assign event.target.records to a variable; that's what the records variable returns anyways.